# .NET System::String to UTF8-bytes stored in char*

Tags: .net, c++, string, char, unmanaged

I am wrapping some unmanaged C++ code inside a .NET project. For this I need to convert `System::String` to UTF8-bytes stored in `char*`.

I am unsure if this is the best or even a correct way to do this and I'd appreciate if someone could take a look and provide feedback.

Thanks,

/David

```
// Copy into blank VisualStudio C++/CLR command line solution.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

// Test for calling with char* argument.
void MyTest(const char* buffer)
{
    printf_s("%s\n", buffer);
    return;
}

int main()
{

   // Create a UTF-8 encoding.
   UTF8Encoding^ utf8 = gcnew UTF8Encoding;

   // A Unicode string with two characters outside an 8-bit code range.
   String^ unicodeString = L"This unicode string contains two characters with codes outside an 8-bit code range, Pi (\u03a0) and Sigma (\u03a3).";
   Console::WriteLine(unicodeString);

   // Encode the string.
   array<Byte>^encodedBytes = utf8->GetBytes(unicodeString);

   // Get pointer to unmanaged char array
   int size = Marshal::SizeOf(encodedBytes[0]) * encodedBytes->Length;
   IntPtr pnt = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(size);
   Marshal::Copy(encodedBytes, 0, pnt, encodedBytes->Length);

   // Ugly, but necessary?
   char *charPnt= (char *)pnt.ToPointer();
   MyTest(charPnt);
   Marshal::FreeHGlobal(pnt);

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. You don't need to create an encoder instance, you can use the static instances.
2. If the called function doesn't expect a pointer to the HGlobal heap you can just use plain C/C++ memory allocation (new or malloc) for the buffer.
3. In your example the function doesn't take ownership so you don't need a copy at all, just pin the buffer.

Something like:

```
// Encode the text as UTF8
array<Byte>^ encodedBytes = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(unicodeString);

// prevent GC moving the bytes around while this variable is on the stack
pin_ptr<Byte> pinnedBytes = &encodedBytes[0];

// Call the function, typecast from byte* -> char* is required
MyTest(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pinnedBytes), encodedBytes->Length);
```

Or if you need the string zero-terminated like most C functions (including the example in the OP) then you should probably add a zero byte.

```
// Encode the text as UTF8, making sure the array is zero terminated
array<Byte>^ encodedBytes = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(unicodeString + "\0");

// prevent GC moving the bytes around while this variable is on the stack
pin_ptr<Byte> pinnedBytes = &encodedBytes[0];

// Call the function, typecast from byte* -> char* is required
MyTest(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pinnedBytes));
```

Comment: In this example, I don't see how `pinnedBytes` will get a zero terminator on it. Is there some magic which guarantees this? Or is that left as an exercise for the reader?

Comment: @StilesCrisis oops, you are right, I must have overlooked the fact that the OP was passing his char pointer to printf %s which needs it zero terminated. In practice the pinned bytes are usually followed by zero bytes so it probably would work anyways, but I don't know of any rules which would guarantee that. I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: Just for everyone reading this answer, the null character `\0` must be enclosed by double-quote, like this `"\0"`, otherwise it would end up something like `GetBytes(unicodeString.Concat(0))` if you use single-quote version `GetBytes(unicodeString + '\0')`